# PyTorch: 'RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float' pytorch geometric error

Tags: python, pytorch, networkx, pytorch-geometric

This post follows on from a previous post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70452465/how-to-load-in-graph-from-networkx-into-pytorch-geometric-and-set-node-features) (I will use the same made up example for the code below). I have read the other posts about these errors, but I don't think those solution methods are helping me.

**Goal**: Implement a node classification task (similar to Cora, but different application)

**Question**: How do I fix these errors I am getting?

1. 'IndexError: tensors used as indices must be long, byte or bool tensors' (getting this in my main code)
2. 'RuntimeError: expected scalar type Long but found Float' (getting this in my code when I am trying to reproduce the code in a public-friendly form, as well as error above)

**Context**:
Here is the code below: (being used within Google Colab)

For the example below, I will be attempting to classify the class of a node, and each node will have a feature vector of length 5 (just completely made up for now). I will be using the adjacency matrix:

A = [(0, 1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0, 0)]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
%matplotlib inline

import torch
from torch.nn import Linear
import torch.nn.functional as F
torch.__version__

import sklearn
from sklearn import preprocessing

# install pytorch geometric
!pip install torch-scatter torch-sparse torch-cluster torch-spline-conv torch-geometric -f https://data.pyg.org/whl/torch-1.10.0+cpu.html

from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv
from torch_geometric.utils.convert import to_networkx, from_networkx

# Make the networkx graph
G = nx.Graph()

# Add some cars (just do 4 for now)
G.add_nodes_from([
      (1, {'y': 0}),
      (2, {'y': 1}),
      (3, {'y': 2}),
      (4, {'y': 3}),
      (5, {'y': 4}),
])

# Add some edges --> A = [(0, 1, 0, 1, 1), (1, 0, 1, 1, 0), (0, 1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 0, 1, 0, 0)]
G.add_edges_from([
                  (1, 2), (1, 4), (1, 5),
                  (2, 3), (2, 4),
                  (3, 2), (3, 5), 
                  (4, 1), (4, 2),
                  (5, 1), (5, 3)
])

# add the price data to the graph as node features
for node in G.nodes():
  G.nodes[node]['x'] = np.random.rand(5) * 5

# Convert the graph into PyTorch geometric
pyg_graph = from_networkx(G)

# Create the train_mask and test_mask

# Split the data 
train_ratio = 0.2
num_nodes = data.x.shape[0]
num_train = int(num_nodes * train_ratio)

print(f'The number of training nodes is: {num_train}\n')

idx = [i for i in range(num_nodes)]

np.random.shuffle(idx)
train_mask = torch.full_like(data.y, False, dtype=bool)
train_mask[idx[:num_train]] = True
test_mask = torch.full_like(data.y, False, dtype=bool)
test_mask[idx[num_train:]] = True
```

I think everything above is correct (I was lucky enough to receive some help with the latter portions of it). At a high level, the code above:

a. Creates the graph (G) in `networkx`

b. Assigns brands (i.e. classes) and the feature vectors

c. Converts the graph to PyTorch geometric

d. Defines the train_mask and test_mask for PyTorch geometric

Most of the code below comes from the Pytorch Geometric Cora tutorial code, with only a little bit changed once or twice (e.g. names of variables). However, this is causing errors so keen to learn what is causing them.

```
# change the name of the variable to match the name in the online Cora tutorial
data = pyg_graph

from torch_geometric.nn import GCNConv

class GCN(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_channels):
        super().__init__()
        torch.manual_seed(1234567)
        self.conv1 = GCNConv(len(data.x[0]), hidden_channels)  # in this case, we set num_features = len(data.x[0])
        self.conv2 = GCNConv(hidden_channels, num_nodes)    # in this case, num_classes = num_nodes

    def forward(self, x, edge_index):
        x = self.conv1(x, edge_index)
        x = x.relu()
        x = F.dropout(x, p=0.5, training=self.training)
        x = self.conv2(x, edge_index)
        return x

model = GCN(hidden_channels=16)
print(model)
```

This is where I now try to change the type of the variables to prevent the errors.

```
data.x = data.x.type(LongTensor)
data.y = data.y.type(LongTensor)
```

Now the code continues:

```
data.train_mask = train_mask
data.test_mask = test_mask

model = GCN(hidden_channels=16)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.01, weight_decay=5e-4)
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

def train():
      model.train()
      optimizer.zero_grad()  # Clear gradients.
      out = model(data.x, data.edge_index)  # Perform a single forward pass.
      loss = criterion(out[data.train_mask], data.y[data.train_mask])  # Compute the loss solely based on the training nodes.
      loss.backward()  # Derive gradients.
      optimizer.step()  # Update parameters based on gradients.
      return loss

def test():
      model.eval()
      out = model(data.x, data.edge_index)
      pred = out.argmax(dim=1)  # Use the class with highest probability.
      test_correct = pred[data.test_mask] == data.y[data.test_mask]  # Check against ground-truth labels.
      test_acc = int(test_correct.sum()) / int(data.test_mask.sum())  # Derive ratio of correct predictions.
      return test_acc


for epoch in range(1, 101):
    loss = train()
    print(f'Epoch: {epoch:03d}, Loss: {loss:.4f}')\
```

As shown in the lines `data.x = data.x.type(LongTensor)`/etc. I have tried those solutions but nothing seems to be working. Also, for some reason when doing that line in my example notebook (the version made up for this post), I am getting an error:
NameError: name 'LongTensor' is not defined' but I will put this in another post as I don't seem to be able to import `torch_C`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and hope everyone is having a happy holiday season.