# OSMNX graph to torch_geometry Error: "Could not infer dtype of Point"

Tags: python, graph, pytorch, osmnx, pytorch-geometric

I am a freshman in graph neural networks. Recently I have been struggling with doing TGCN on the transportation network.

I have a lot of Geospatial data points with timestamps in one area. I want to map /summarize these data to node and edge features of a graph representing the transportation network.

What I have achieved：

- [x] Load the data points to Geopandas Dataframe
- [x] Retrieve a graph on the transportation network: The OSMNX helped me a lot and generated a NetworkX graph by retrieving info from OpenStreetMap
- [x] Paring the points to nodes and edges of the NetworkX graph
- [x] Generate new node or edge features based on paired points
- [x] Build an updated Networkx graph from nodes and edges
- [ ] Conduct TGCN training

The next step now is how to conduct TGCN training on NetworkX graphs?? I only found some tutorials on TGCN modeling using Pytorch Geometrics. So I tried to transfer the NetworkX graph from OSMNX to torch geometrics. I followed the steps in [How to load in graph from networkx into PyTorch geometric and set node features and labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70452465/how-to-load-in-graph-from-networkx-into-pytorch-geometric-and-set-node-features)

The problem is the referred tutorial build graph with NetworkX directly. I filtered out the features that I needed and used the OSMNX ox.graph_from_gdfs(new_nodes, new_edges) to build the NetworkX. It is ensured that the features in nodes and edges are numeric (except the geometry column).

```
new_nodes
```

[image]

```
new_edges = temp_edges.drop(['osmid','oneway','lanes',
                             'highway', 'ref', 'name', 'maxspeed', 'bridge', 'access', 
                             'uni', 'max_speed', 'min_speed', 'avg_speed', 'count'], axis=1)
new_edges
```

[image]

```
new_graph = ox.graph_from_gdfs(new_nodes, new_edges)
new_graph
```

<networkx.classes.multidigraph.MultiDiGraph at 0x28c70c8ad90>

**The error arises when transfering the OSMNX NetworkX graph to torch geometric**

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import torch
from torch_geometric.utils.convert import from_networkx


# Convert the graph into PyTorch geometric
G = new_graph
pyg_graph = from_networkx(G, group_node_attrs = ["street_count"] , group_edge_attrs = ["length"])
# pyg_graph = from_networkx(G)

print(pyg_graph)
```

[image]

So, anyone knows how to transfer the OSMNX graph to torch_geometric? Or How to train TGCN models on OSMNX graphs? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with OSMNX graphs but I just ran into a similar issue where the error message

> RuntimeError: Could not infer dtype of CLASS

comes from `from_networkx()` or more specifically, the `convert()` subroutine it called.

I fixed the issue by creating a no-data networkx graph:

```
no_data_graph = networkx.DiGraph() # change to Graph() if your graph is undirected
no_data_graph.add_nodes_from(G.nodes())
no_data_graph.add_edges_from(G.edges())
```

I guess in your case you can create a new graph that contains only numeric data fields and remove any data field that is of type `Point`.

Answer (score 0):

I confirm "myx". In order to solve this issue you must create a new empty graph with:

```html
new_undirected_graph = nx.Graph()
new_directed_graph = nx.DiGraph()

// use add_nodes_from, add_edges_from
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue with this loading from a graphML file.

The networkX nx.read_graphml adds some metadata keys that from_networkx doesn't handle. They come in or can come in, as an empty dict. In your case it looks like point is the empty dict. Even with something in I think it would not be working as intended, but that is a bug report for pyg rather than an SO problem.

The easiest solution I found was in here
[https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/main/osmnx/io.py][1]

Which implies that OSMNX does the same.

and is to "pop" the offending empty dictionaries

````py
    import networkx as nx
    from random import randint,random
    from torch_geometric.utils.convert import from_networkx
    
    #Generate a graph with example data
    g = nx.generators.classic.complete_graph(5,nx.Graph)
    
    #nodes
    nprop1 = {n:randint(0,50) for n in g.nodes()}
    nprop2 = {n:random() for n in g.nodes()}
    nx.set_node_attributes(g,nprop1,'nprop1')
    nx.set_node_attributes(g,nprop2,'nprop2')

    #edges
    eprop1 = {e:randint(0,10) for e in g.edges()}
    eprop2 = {e:random() for e in g.edges()}
    nx.set_edge_attributes(g,eprop1,'eprop1')
    nx.set_edge_attributes(g,eprop2,'eprop2')

    #THIS WORKS
    G1 = from_networkx(g,group_node_attrs=all,group_edge_attrs=all)

    #THIS DOES NOT
    nx.write_graphml(g,'gml_test.graphml')
    g2 = nx.read_graphml('gml_test.graphml')
    G2 = from_networkx(g2,group_edge_attrs=all,group_node_attrs=all)

    # remove node_default and edge_default metadata keys if they exist
    g2.graph.pop("node_default", None)
    g2.graph.pop("edge_default", None)

    #THIS NOW DOES
    G2 = from_networkx(g2,group_edge_attrs=all,group_node_attrs=all)
    ```


[1]: https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx/blob/main/osmnx/io.py
````